# Tweepy Twitter get all tweet replies of particular user

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to get all replies of this particular user. So this particular user have reply_to_user_id_str of 151791801. I tried to print out all the replies but I'm not sure how. However, I only manage to print out only 1 of the replies. Can anyone help me how to print out all the replies?[image]

My codes are:

```
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id="253346744").pages(1):
    for item in page:
            if item.in_reply_to_user_id_str == "151791801":
                print item.text
                a = api.get_status(item.in_reply_to_status_id_str)
                print a.text
```

[image: Output:]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, find the retweet thread of your conversation with your service provider:

```
# Find the last tweet
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id="253346744").pages(1):
    for item in page:
        if item.in_reply_to_user_id_str == "151791801":
            last_tweet = item
```

The variable `last tweet` will contain their last retweet to you. From there, you can loop back to your original tweet:

```
# Loop until the original tweet
while True:
    print(last_tweet.text)
    prev_tweet = api.get_status(last_tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str)
    last_tweet = prev_tweet
    if not last_tweet.in_reply_to_status_id_str:
        break
```

It's not pretty, but it gets the job done.
Good luck!

Comment: thanks! It works. Just one question, do you know how you avoid tweet limit? Tried exception but does'nt work

Comment: Do you mean twitter API rate limits? You can set the wait_on_rate_limit parameter to true when you are setting up the api. For example: `api = tweepy.API(auth_args, wait_on_rate_limit=True)`.

Answer (score 5):

```
user_name = "@nameofuser"

replies = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='to:{} filter:replies'.format(user_name)) tweet_mode='extended').items()

while True:
    try:
        reply = replies.next()
        if not hasattr(reply, 'in_reply_to_user_id_str'):
            continue
        if str(reply.in_reply_to_user_id_str) == "151791801":
           logging.info("reply of :{}".format(reply.full_text))

    except tweepy.RateLimitError as e:
        logging.error("Twitter api rate limit reached".format(e))
        time.sleep(60)
        continue

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        logging.error("Tweepy error occured:{}".format(e))
        break

    except StopIteration:
        break

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Failed while fetching replies {}".format(e))
        break
```

Comment: I downvoted it but the answer is actually correct. Would upvote it as soon as it gets unlocked.

Comment: @RaunaqJain no problem :)