# Get latest direct message + sender id based on user - Tweepy

Tags: python, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I was wondering how I could get the latest message in a DM using Tweepy as well as the ID of the sender. I would retrieve this conversation using the ID of the person I am DM'ing For example:

If user 1 has an ID of `1188288042026635265` and user 2 has an ID of `1317999444177129476` and the conversation looked something like this:

```
user 1: Hello
user 2: Hello how are you?
user 1: I am good
user 2: that is good to hear
```

For the sake of this example, let's say user 1 is the user I am using Tweepy from. I would retrieve this conversation using `1317999444177129476` Then the method would return `that is good to hear` and `1317999444177129476`.I appreciate the help in advance, thank you!

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497631/tweepy-twitter-get-all-tweet-replies-of-particular-user/31500076

Comment: @YashMakan I think those are more for Twitter Threads rather than Twitter Direct Messages